# CakePHP returning double array from find('list) query

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array

I'm using cakephp and am getting back a "double array" where it is giving me 2 arrays where it should be 1, I have looked into the issue as far as cakephp and can't figure it out and just want to move past this for now so I am wondering if anyone knows how to unset a second array if a variable has 2 arrays.. below is the print_r of the array, its just one variable that has this, which I find odd.. so I want to make it so there is not a 2nd set of duplicate values, if I do an array_push it pushes both values for that index into the resulting new array index so that won't work

one variable is equal to the following:

```
Array ( [0] => 42 [1] => 62 ) Array ( [0] => 42 [1] => 62 )
```

EDIT:

This is not an issue of my printing out the array twice accidentally, as I said above, with a foreach array_push of the variable, i end up with this, which is odd:

```
Array ( [0] => 4242 [1] => 6262 )
```

EDIT:

This is the cakephp database call that I am using, I know I didn't ask this in regards to cakephp but since some people think this is impossible i am posting this just so you can see what it does if you want

```
    $specificfields_array = $this->Mymodel->find('list', array('fields' =>'Mymodel.id'),
                'conditions' => array('emailgroup' => $categorynumber, 'sent' => '0');));
```

EDIT:

This is what a "foreach" array_push is:

```
$mynewarray = array();

foreach ($specificfields as $specificfields_current) {

array_push ($mynewarray, $specificfields_current);

}
```

Comment: Where's the code that prints this ?

Comment: its just a print_r($variable).. as I said, its coming from a cakephp database call so unless you use cakephp its not going to be replicable.. I can pursue the cakephp avenue more of figuring out why it does this, I just figured there would be a way to get it down to one variable, I may just have it count the characters in each index and then "halve" it so i am left with just the one value for each index after an array_push

Comment: So when you comment out `print_r($variable)` both of them disappear?

Comment: try `print_r($variable); die()` and see if you still see two.

Comment: already have been.. thats not the issue.. I edited OP with my cakephp post, I will have to look into this more from cakephp as its what is giving this strange output

Comment: what the hell is a foreach array_push?

Comment: @Artefacto i was talking in shorthand, ok i put that code in the edit too

Comment: What does `$fieldsarray` contain, and what fields are in the table associated with `Mymodel`?

Comment: @MAtt.. sorry it was part of a component so I had it all variablized, i will go back and get the info and edit it with the values of the variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the controller, the model and the view file with your print_r calls to the http://bin.cakephp.org/ site and post the links back here so we can see all of your code?

Comment: I think it was some problem with the way I was doing where it appeared that way.. I apologize for this question as it was poorly organized.. it has, however, led me to re-think my method of coding so that I better compartamentalize things to stay on top of whats going on (by using lots of small library modules).. =)

Answer (score 1):

A variable cannot "have two arrays". It can be one array that has two arrays nested. The scenario you describe is impossible (probably there are two `print_r` there or there is a `<` character hiding stuff – check the HTML source).

Comment: no its not as its showing this exact ouput for me, I realize its not supposed to occur but I am getting that exact output from: print_r($variable)

Comment: @Rick I'd bet on two print_r or a print_r being called twice.

Comment: No, really its not, I already thought of that, I have even done an array_push, as I said in the OP and it does the same thing where it will put the 2 duplicate values from the 1 index into a new index, so it would end up being Array ( [0] => 4242 [1] => 6262 )

Comment: @Rick This just does not happen.